# Simple java issue: object declaration

Tags: java

```
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
```

If I declare frame1 by doing `JFrame frame1;` is the `JFrame` the type of `Object` or is it something else? What does `JFrame` do, why cant I omit it?

Comment: JFrame frame1; is declaring a variable that is an object of type JFrame. It is called 'frame1' The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor. What is a JFrame?: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Comment: You should go though this first, [Creating Objects...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it defines the type of your `frame1` variable. Java is a strongly-typed language, and all variables must have a type defined. Many Java classes extend other classes or implement other interfaces, and there are often many types that the variable can have. While `JFrame` is the "natural" choice here, you could also write, for example:

```
Component frame1 = new JFrame();
```

because `JFrame` extends `Component`. So, the language insists on the type being specified, even if there is a naturally "obvious" type implied where it is initialised on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();`

This is a variable declaration statement.
It creates a variable (reference) called `frame1` of type `JFrame` that points to a new object of type `JFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame  frame1;
```

Tells that the  reference `frame1`  is of type `JFrame` .

So while `instantiating/assigning` it checks the type.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `JFrame` is both the type of the variable and the type of the object in the variable. When you write `JFrame frame1`, you're creating a variable named `frame1` that holds a `JFrame`; the actual object you put into that variable can be a `JFrame` or any `JFrame` subclass. When you write `new JFrame()`, you're creating a new object of type `JFrame` to put in the `frame1` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring like:

```
JFrame frame1;
```

means frame1 is a reference of type JFrame and it does not create any object where as

```
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
```

Creates a new Object of type JFrame which is referred by frame1.

As illustrated by this figure below:

[image]

[Source](http://java-espresso.blogspot.in/2011/09/3java-basics-class-and-objects-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have declared that `frame1` is type of Object/class `JFrame` by:

```
JFrame frame1;
```

and by

```
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
```

means you have have instantiate the declared `frame1` of type Object/class `JFrame`

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
```

is actually an object declaration and initialization which is the basic idea in object oriented programming concept.

In OOPs Object declaration and initialization is a 2 step process.

```
Step 1:Object declarion -----> JFrame frame;
```

Here actually a reference variable(frame) of type of that particular class(jFrame) is decalring but nothing is assigned to it ans hence it has null value assigned to it by default.

```
Step2:Object initialization--> frame=new Jframe();
```

Here the actaul object declaration takes place which is done by dynamically by new keyword and it is here the constructor JFrame() is called. Hence that object memory refernce is assigned to 'frame' refernce variable.

So if you decalre

```
JFrame frame;
```

nothig happens until you initialise it to

```
frame=new Jframe();
```